# Proof of knowledge and replay attacks

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, fiat-shamir

I was reading the ZK proof of knowledge of Schnorr and fiat shamir transformation, and I figured out that replay attacks are possible. Why these protocols don't take into account this attack? That seems very strange.

Thank you.

Comment: You failed to mention what attack

Comment: I think you need to provide more information. What information could be replayed to effectively attack either of these protocols? And if there is anything else to it, how would the attack look from there?

Comment: @JacobH I think about the Fiat Shamir non interactive protocol. The proof can be replayed.

Comment: @Adam54 Can you link this protocol? AFAIK, Fiat-Shamir is just a transformation for digitally signing a ZK proof (and making it non-interactive)  but not a full protocol in itself.

As for the replay-ability of it, generally ZK proofs involve some random variable, meaning that even if you record the messages, the next instance of the protocol will be entirely different, leaving your recorded message useless.

Comment: @JacobH What I mean is that a signature is replayable. If the verifier does not record the previous proofs or does not check them at each authentication, a proof can be replayed.

Comment: @Adam54 you still did not provide a protocol. Consider a CRS model, it is statistically improbable that the same public information will be reused. Because the signature includes this information, it is by proxy statistically improbable to be reused.

Answer (score 1):

In General: ZK protocols become insecure if computed concurrently; I think this is what you are referring to. If the protocol is run in parallel, an adversary could request a proof of two relationships and produce a witness for the first with the knowledge gained from the second prover-output. When run concurrently, this attack cannot be executed because the adversary cannot receive a second commitment on the same relation to learn/produce a witness for the first. As far as I know, there is no protocol that achieves concurrent security.

Comment: That was not my question but this is really interesting. Thank you.